# add or union single object based on keys in an array of objects using lodash

Tags: arrays, lodash

I have created an array of object from the data from database. I wanted to plot data on pie chart but I am facing difficulties to make such format.

Below is the final result, I created so far:

```
let natinalityBreakdown = [
{Omani: Array(2), Pakistani: Array(2), Indian: Array(3), Test: Array(1)},
{Omani: Array(6), Chinese: Array(1)},
{Omani: Array(51), OMANi: Array(1), Pakistani: Array(5)}
];
```

using below code:

```
let natinalityBreakdowna = [];
        _.forEach(company, function(company) {
          const linkedCompanyUsers= _(driver)
              .filter(d => d.companyId === company.companyId)
              .value();
           console.log(linkedCompanyUsers);
           let nationalityBreakdown = _.groupBy(linkedCompanyUsers, "nationality");
           console.log(nationalityBreakdown);
           nationalityBreakdown = _.omit(nationalityBreakdown, "undefined");
           console.log(nationalityBreakdown);
           natinalityBreakdowna.push(nationalityBreakdown);
        });
        console.log(natinalityBreakdowna);
```

**I wanted such result in object as below:**

```
{Omani: Array(59), Pakistani: Array(7), Indian: Array(3), Test: Array(1), Chinese: Array(1), OMANi: Array(1)}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to add the people of same nationality in same group using `array#concat` in an object.

```
var result = natinalityBreakdown.reduce(function(res, obj){
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
    res[k] = res[k] || [];
    res[k] = res[k].concat(obj[k]);
 });
 return res;
},{});
```